# Scroll to top of accordion when opened using bootstrap-ui

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using angular and bootstrap-ui to create accordions using  and  tags. I want to scroll to the top when opened, used to be easy by using shown.bs.collapse event but not with boostrap-ui.

Comment: Can you show some code so that we don't need to do everrrythinggg

Comment: This websites code thing doesn't work properly, it cuts off after the first line. I even tried using the backticks.

Comment: you need to indent all code by atleast 4 spaces and have 1 blank line between your code and any text

Comment: Have you tried the `$anchorScroll` service? you can probably use this to scroll to the top of your accordion somehow each time it is opened

Comment: I have used it before, but not sure how it would work with that

Comment: I did try indenting the code but it just doesn't register it on the newline